# GIS in medical geography

Tags: medical-geography

I am interested in knowing about current trends in application of GIS for medical geography other than disease/epidemic mapping, heath atlas, availability of health infrastructure (hospitals, blood banks, primary health centers etc).

Comment: removed gis tag; it's "meta" for this site: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Answer (score 9):

There is a very detailed list of GIS usage in health [here](http://www.spatialhydrology.com/health/health.htm) and [here](http://www-sul.stanford.edu/depts/gis/medical.html).

For the most recent trends, ESRI holds a conference on the subject in Denver in October, and you might be interested with the [agenda and keynote](http://www.esri.com/events/health/index.html).

Some anecdotes:

- [Google flu trends](http://www.google.org/flutrends/) is a neat project, which estimates flu activity by measuring and mapping Google searches for the term "flu".
- It is always nice to look at the (probably) first usage of GIS in health: [John Snow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Snow_(physician))'s link between clusters of cholera outbreaks and water pumps during the London Cholera epidemic of 1854.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You might want to have a look at the recent articles in:

- [International Journal of Health Geographics](http://www.ij-healthgeographics.com/)
- [Spatial and Spatio-temporal Epidemiology](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/journaldescription.cws_home/719813/description#description)

Also [this](http://www.ted.com/talks/bill_davenhall_your_health_depends_on_where_you_live.html) TED talk gives a nice overview of what might be done in the future.

Answer (score 2):

For a short overview of the current trends, you can have a look at [the program](http://www.geoforum.dk/Admin/Public/DWSDownload.aspx?File=%2fFiles%2fFiler%2fGISandHealth2010%2fWorkshop_programme.pdf) of this [workshop on GIS and Health](http://www.geoforum.dk/Default.aspx?ID=8740&gmId=128).

Answer (score 2):

I've seem GIS being used by several medical geography applications in Brazil. Some of them are run by the federal government that track obituaries and COD using UN CID codes.

Also, there is an application being used in my home town to track car accidents, but still not GIS enabled (I took a part in helping the city to spatially enable it, but I don't thin it went forward).

I can provide two articles I wrote (one on dengue control and one on tracking car accidents, but they are both in portuguese). There also [my Bsc. Geography thesis](http://blog.geoprocessamento.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/Monografia_George.pdf) available online.
If you want the articles, let me know.

Comment: Do you have an English version of your B.Sc Geography thesis?

Comment: lol. Love your music credits :)

Comment: @SRG: sorry, I don't. Since it's written in a more academic approach, Google Translator might give you good results.

@Jason: I only work with music on :P